# Why "socket.sendall(data)" Doesn't send data to client after freezing (py to Mpy)

Tags: python, micropython

Im building an (Accesspoint - client) device using esp8266 or esp32
the entire system works well until i try freezing it .

***Problem : after freezing the ".py"(freezing is .py->.mpy - converting to precompiled file) file which contains socket functions , the (socket.sendall(data)) doesnt send data to client and (socket.recv(buff)) works well.***

**what i have done ?**

1- the whole code works well when nothing is freezed

2- Mpy-cross version is controlled and it doesn't have compatibility issues with the firmware version
(mpy-cross ver :1.14  upythonversion(esp32):esp32-20210902-v1.17_2 )

3- I reduced the HTML-page size (on a very small size of html code the freezed mpy file works
well . which is useless) - i put a simple html page in a dropbox link below which doesnt work
after freezing.

4- actually the main code is much bigger than this example - more than 10 pages plus jsons and so
on , i had to make it easier to put in here .

edit1 : if {Connection: Keep-Alive\n\n} changes to {Connection: close\n\n}
then the mpy works - but on small webpages.
and doesnt work on much bigger pages

*Python version : 3.9-64bit
IDE : upycraft 1.1
soc : esp32-wroom32 , and esp8266-e12*

and here is the sample code which works fine in py - and doesn't work in MPY

HTML page inside esp server:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/41hqpkyk5vzphro/RadnomPage.txt?dl=0

MicroPython code:

```
def EstablishWifiAP(Input):
  if Input==True:
    gc.collect()
    print('link2>>' + str(gc.mem_free()))
    ssid = 'RANDOM_AP'
    password = '12345678'
    station = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    station.active(True)
    station.config(essid=ssid, password=password)
    
    sleep(1)
    while station.isconnected() == False:
      pass
        
    sleep(1)

    print('Connection successful')
    print(station.ifconfig())
    gc.collect()
  else:
    station = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
    station.active(False)

#EOF
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------


def ManageWeb(Input):
  if Input==True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', 80))
    s.listen(1)
    sleep(3) 
    while True:

      try:
        if gc.mem_free() < 10000:
          gc.collect()
          
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        request  = ' '
        gc.collect()
        conn.settimeout(7)
        request = conn.recv(800)
        print(str(request))
        gc.collect()
        conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
        conn.send('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n')
        conn.send('Connection: Keep-Alive\n\n')
        gc.collect() 
        conn.sendall(HtmlData)
        gc.collect()
        del request 
        gc.collect()
        print('c>>' + str(gc.mem_free()))
        conn.close()

      except OSError as e:
        conn.close()
        gc.collect()
        print('Os error Connection closed')
        print(e.errno)
  else:
    print('socket Deactivated')
```

This is my first StackOverflow question , I tried so much to ask a good guestion :)

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing"? Also which line is pending? Also, you use lots of `gc.collect()` and things like `del request` that don't do much.

Comment: the freezing {.py to .mpy (pre-compiled file)} which I might be wrong in using the (freezing) phrase.
by the way, all " gc.collect()" lines, and that del request is just for freeing ram in esp8266 

the pending line is "conn.sendall(HtmlData)" which sends data correctly when I use .py file
and doesn't send data when I use .mpy file instead of .py one.